# SQL only delete values in specific colums?

Tags: sql

What I am trying to do is delete all rows from a table, but leave values in 1 specific column from the table.

For example the table 'member' with the columns 'membernumber', 'name', lastname' and 'zipcode', I only want to keep all the zipcodes as they are, but delete all other data.

Comment: If you are deleting a row, you are by definition, deleting the **entire** row; you can't leave a column is situ. What you want is an `UPDATE` not a `DELETE`.

Comment: Also, please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. [[tag:sql-server]] and [[tag:mysql]] are *completely* different products.

Comment: You will have to move the data you want to keep to another table before doing the delete then. A row is a row and you cannot keep half a row

Comment: If we ignore the "delete" terminology for a moment, you may just be after `ALTER TABLE .. DROP COLUMN`, which removes a column from the table (and with it all data in it for all rows, obviously). Otherwise, you'll have to be more specific about how the data looks now, and how you expect it to look afterwards.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for pointing the tag out. I am completely new to SQL and such so I am still learning about the difference and all. Will keep this in mind next time!

Comment: You should, however, [edit] your question to retag the correct RDBMS, @Xavvey .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your table structure, you use Alter Table along with Drop Column instead of Delete which is for your records. Here is a sample:

```
ALTER TABLE member
DROP COLUMN membernumber, name, lastname
```

Comment: I am not trying to alter the structure. To be more precise: I am doing an assignment for school and one of the things is to make a PHP page that deletes all rows from my database and only keeps the zipcodes in there. The database contains about 4 tables, with 1 of them being 'zipcodes' with the columns 'zipcodes', 'residence' and 'adres'. Zipcode being the PK in this table and a FK in another table (tablename member).